# filter on CollectionProperties gives me all 4 records instead of 2

Tags: c#

I have a list `lstCollectionInstances` which has 4 collection instance,

```
var lstCollectionInstances = new List<CollectionInstance>
        {
            new CollectionInstance
            {
                Name = "A",
                CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                {
                    new CollectionProperty {Name = "P1", Value = 10, DataType = "D"}
                }
            },
            new CollectionInstance
            {
                Name = "A",
                CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                {
                    new CollectionProperty {Name = "P2", Value = "H1", DataType = "S"}
                }
            },
            new CollectionInstance
            {
                Name = "B",
                CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                {
                    new CollectionProperty {Name = "P1", Value = 20, DataType = "D"}
                }
            },
            new CollectionInstance
            {
                Name = "B",
                CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                {
                    new CollectionProperty {Name = "P2", Value = "H2", DataType = "S"}
                }
            },
        };
```

Now when I filter it based on `CollectionProperty` data types `D` it's should give me 2 records, but below code giving me all 4 records, what is missing here?

```
var X = lstCollectionInstances.Select(x => new CollectionInstance
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            CollectionProperties = x.CollectionProperties.Where(cp => cp.DataType == "D").ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: WHat is type of Value property from CollectionProperty class? In first and third item you are setting int type (10 and 20), in second and fourth string type ("H1" and "H2")

Comment: It's object type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one selects all instances with a property of type D.

```
var result= lstCollectionInstances
    .Where(x => x.CollectionProperties.Any(y => y.DataType == "D"))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're executing `Select` in each item of `lstCollectionInstances` and Where in `CollectionProperties`. It will return 4 items which 2 of them have empty `CollectionProperties`. You should execute `Where` first like:

```
  var X = lstCollectionInstances.Where(a => a.CollectionProperties.Any(cp => cp.DataType == "D")).Select(x => new CollectionInstance
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            CollectionProperties = x.CollectionProperties
        }).ToList();
```